# django render an object as html in a template

Tags: django, django-templates

I am trying to render an object in a template like what we can do with forms `{{ form }}` but the output is turned into text and not html code. How to really include html code?

```
my_object = MyObject()
{{ my_object }}
```

The class:

```
from django.template import Context, Template
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

class MyObject(object):

    def __str__(self):
        return self.render()

    def render(self):
        t = Template('<p>This is your <span>{{ message }}</span>.</p>')
        c = Context({'message': 'Your message'})
        html = t.render(c)
        return mark_safe(html)
```

Comment: You should be implementing `__unicode__` instead of `__str__`.

Comment: That works thanks. I used __str__ because I saw that is what was used in the BaseForm class. ``def __str__(self):
        return self.as_table()`` I did not see a __unicode__ method defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be implementing `__unicode__` instead of `__str__`. The templating module stringifies context variables as unicode.

Answer (score 0):

If the attempt is to get html on to the page then you should be using `{{myobject|safe}}`. That should render the `HTML` code instead of text

Comment: Sorry about that i did not see the mark safe function, if that is the case try using mark_for_escaping,

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
{% autoescape off %}
{{ info }}
{% endautoescape off %}
```

But you must be care to avoid xss vulnerabilities.