# Django - i always get my profile when i what to view another users profile

Tags: python, django, redirect, orm, profile

Whenever i tried to view other people profile, it always return my own profile again, i don't really know what's wrong and i have tried calling `request.user` but it seems not to work

views.py

```
def UserProfile(request, username):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
    url_name = resolve(request.path).url_name
    
    context = {
        'profile':profile,
        'url_name':url_name,
    }

    return render(request, 'userauths/profile.html', context)
```

urls.py main project

```
from userauths.views import UserProfile

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('users/', include('userauths.urls')),
    path('<username>/', UserProfile, name='profile'),

]
```

index.html

```
{% for creator in creators %}
     <a href="{% url 'profile' creator.user %}"><img class="avatar-img rounded-circle" src="{{creator.user.profile.image.url}}" alt="creators image" ></a></div>
     <h5 class="card-title"><a href="{% url 'profile' creator.user %}"> 
      {{creator.user.profile.first_name}} {{creator.user.profile.last_name}} {% if creator.verified %} <i class="bi bi-patch-check-fill text-info smsall" ></i> {% else %}{% endif %} </a></h5>
     <p class="mb-2">{{creator.user.profile.bio}}</p></div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can you share what `username` is in the views.py?

Comment: Is it `request.user`?

Comment: @Robo when i user request.user it just throws back my profile, instead of showing other profiles

Comment: @Robo what exactly do you want me share about username, i do not really understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just fixed it now, in my profile.html, i am using `{{request.user.profile.first_name}}` to display the informations. I was supposed to use `{{profile.first_name}}` etc, and that was it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
<a href="{% url 'profile' creator.user %}">
```

you should try:

```
<a href="{% url 'profile' creator.user.username %}">
```

From the presumably working statement `get_object_or_404(User, username=username)` I assume that `username` is a field (hopefully, unique) of the `User`. So you should pass it onto the URL, not the entire `User` model.

Comment: I think the user model has a `__str__` function which returns `self.username` am I right?

Comment: Django templates use `__unicode__`, not `__str__` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22113645/12914274)).

Comment: @Robo yes, it has a function that return self.username

Comment: @YevgeniyKosmak so please what do you reccoment me to do now

Comment: Precisely a things I mentioned in my answer. If it doesn’t solves your issue, please tell me what links it does generate. HTML code I mean.